# Asymptotics of divisor function

Tags: asymptotics, divisor-counting-function

I know that the definition of a perfect number is that its divisor function value is equal to double the number, i.e.,

$$\sigma(n) = 2n$$

By accident I came across the number $250801742479451287$, which divisor function value is almost equal to itself, i.e.,

$$\frac{\sigma(250801742479451287)}{250801742479451287}=\frac{250824161834757504}{250801742479451287}=1.00008939...$$

By playing around, it seems that this might not be some special case, and probably in general, the higher the $n$, the more often and more closer to $1$ we happen to be with the ratio $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$.

My wording might be not correct, but is there something known about the asymptotics of $\sigma(n)$ or even better about the ratio $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$? Is it bounded? Does it converge? 
If so, does it mean that the higher the $n$, the less likely are the perfect numbers (multi-perfect numbers)? Thanks.

Comment: $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$ certainly doesn't converge because there are infinitely many abundant numbers, i.e. numbers with $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n} > 2$, but for the subsequence of prime numbers $\frac{\sigma(p)}{p} = \frac{1+p}p \rightarrow 1$ (which also shows that $\liminf \frac{\sigma(n)}{n} = 1$)

Comment: According to Wikipedia, $\limsup \sigma(n)/(n \log\log n) = e^\gamma$, so $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$ is unbounded.

Comment: The easiest way (computer program) to get a large value for $\sigma(n) / n$ is to write an LCM function ( $LCM(a,b) = ab/\gcd(a,b)$ and use that to let $n = LCM(1,2,3,4,5,6,...,r)$ for some $r.$ All of Ramanujan's families, such as the Superior Highly Composite numbers, or the Colossally Abundant numbers, have roughly that type of pattern as far as prime factorization. However, this lcm thing is a much, much, much easier program than those others.

Comment: although not quite as efficient, $n = r!$ also gives large values of $\sigma(n)/n \; .$

Comment: https://oeis.org/A003418